# Adjusting html element tags using Javascript .outerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, dom, tags

```
<script>
// Wait for the DOM to be fully loaded
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        
const myElement06 = document.getElementById("block-3_17");
if (myElement06) {
     // Find the child div with class "summary-thumbnail-event-date" inside the parent div
  const myChildDiv06 = myElement06.querySelector('.summary-event-date');
  if (myChildDiv06) {
     // Create a new div with the desired HTML structure
     const newMyChildDiv06 = document.createElement('div');
     newMyChildDiv06.className = 'summary-event-date';
     newMyChildDiv06.style.visibility = 'hidden'; // Sets style to hidden.
     // Replace the existing ChildDiv with the newChildDiv
     myChildDiv06.outerHTML = newMyChildDiv06.outerHTML;
  } else {
     console.error('Child div not found');
  }
}
});
</script>
```

I am thinking this should work, but it doesn't.  I want to hide an element on a loaded DOM document.  I have to target a specific id, because there a many tag that use the ".summary-event-date" class.  I was thinking .outerHTML method would do the trick.  It is not?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.